# Docusign Trusted Service Provider API set signature type

Tags: python, docusignapi

I'm working with the Docusign API to integrate a trusted service provider verification for signatures. The API documentation seems to be written for the service provider and not the Docusign API user (me). Within the [TSP Flow](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/tsp-api/tsp101/api-flow/), the user has to select the signature type, at which point docusign redirects the user to that provider for verification and returns a hash that docusign imbeds in the pdf.

My question is, how do you select the signature type within the docusign esignature API? It would seem that it should be handled within the docusign_esign.SignHere() method?

```
discipline = 'Engineer'
EOR_sig_locator = docusign_esignSignHere(
                          anchor_string=f'/{discipline}/',
                          anchor_units='pixels',
                          anchor_y_offset='-5',
                          anchor_x_offset='-40'
                          )
```

Photo below is directly from the Docusign documentation.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the signature type within the Envelopes:create call, set the [recipientSignatureProviders](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_recipients_signers_recipientsignatureproviders) object (part of the Signer recipient object).

The recipientSignatureProvider object can also be set via the [EnvelopeRecipients:create](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/create/) and related calls.

Depending on which AES/QES signature provider is used, additional settings are needed too. For example, some signature providers also require SMS authentication.

Because some of these settings are TSP-specific, it is hard to keep all of the documentation up to date. I recommend that you get the pen working via the DocuSign webapp, then use its API logging to see which attributes it set for the specific pen.